# Increase speed of making thousands of requests to web service

Tags: c#

I have 20,000 products and need to make 2 requests to a web service for each to return a URL.
How can I increase the speed of making all of these calls? Currently, I'm doing something like.

```
private async Task PopulateProductWithImagesAsync(IEnumerable<IProduct> products)
{
    int index = 0;
    int batchSize = 10;
    int productsCount = products.Count();
    var jobs = new List<Task<IMediaSet>>();

    while (index < productsCount)
    {
        jobs.Clear();

        var productsBatch = products.Skip(index).Take(batchSize);

        foreach (var product in productsBatch)
        {
            Task<IMediaSet> job = _scene7Repository.LoadImageUrlAsync(product.Scene7ImageSet); // Make call to get images urls
             jobs.Add(job);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(jobs);

        index += batchSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your webprotocol? HTML?

Comment: consider using PLINQ.

Comment: we need more info, like what kind of app are you building, desktop ? web ? do you control the web service ? what is the goal of the code

Comment: if you control the web service and you get the products from a database using some query then why not let the web service return a list of urls in one request for all products

Comment: I would guess that the biggest issue is always going to be the overhead of making 20,000 calls, regardless of how well you optimize the calling code.  If you can, use a service operation that accepts a list of products and returns a list of URLs.

Comment: How often is `PopulateProductWithImagesAsync` called? Do you cache the results?

Comment: Given the fact you are most likely not going to display all those 20.000 images at the same time... I would consider _not_ preloading them all. You can cache those you fetch, but only fetch them at the moment you actually need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best improovement is usually to process bulk operations as one request. Doing one operation of 20k Products has a lot less overhead then 20k seperate Opeartions. Y+(20k times X) < 20k times (Y+X). If you got control over the other end, add a bulk function.

I doubt your batching is helpfull at all. All you really do is add a loop around a loop. Proper batching would use the bulk approach, but limit it to 10 at at a time.

Multithreading+Tasking: Generally network operations are I/O operations so multitasking and threading should not speed them up. However in practice Webservers are designed to be massively parallel and the protocoll overhead can actually be something CPU relevant (on both sides). So multihreading may speed it up to some degree. Asuming no counter measures were taken on the WebSerice end.

Comment: This for a web api hosted on Azure and for each product, I have to make a request to Scene 7 to return the image urls.

Do you think multithreading would help?

Comment: It will help, until you either reached the bandwidth limit on either end or run into any protection against their code being called that often. Actually what do you even need 20k image links for? Itis not like you could display them all on one page anyway.

Comment: Can you share any code examples or URLS?
We are building an api, and we have 20K products. each product has an scene7 imageset id. We call their service by passing in the imageset id and it returns back a collection of URLs to product images.

I can only make one request for the images at a time.

Comment: If you can only make 1 request at a time and you need all 20k at once, there the only way is to do it how you are already dong it: Piecemeal. The magic bullet would be a redesign. Like not requesting all 20k images at once and maybe caching the results of one request for a while.

Comment: Yes, Piecemeal. We are using Redis Cache and cache the data for 24 hours.